# cleaning a url with php using request url

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website is based on mp3, first my website URL looks like

http://website.com/mp3/song-name

due to some SEO reasons I changed it to

http://website.com/song-name-mp3-download.html using htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^mp3/([^/]+)/?$ $1-mp3-download.html [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

But there is some issues like( uppercase , repeating dash and special character)
  like  http://website.com/Song-Name.---mp3-download.html

I need to change it

I need url like: http://website.com/song-name-mp3-download.html

Thank you Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this PHP code on top of your page:

```
<?php 
// $url is your current page's URL i.e.
$url = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"] . '?' . $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
if ( preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $url) ) {
    header("Location: " . preg_replace('/(\p{P})+/', '$1', strtolower($url))); 
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: how to remove multiple hyphens to single hyphen ?? like http://website.com/----song-name-mp3-download.html to http://website.com/song-name-mp3-download.html using htaccess

Comment: Try: `preg_replace('/^\p{P}+|\p{P}(?=\p{P})/', '', strtolower($url));`

Comment: can you please provide how to replace in htaccess

Comment: It is better to handle this in PHP but if you want a pure htaccess solution it will take much more code. For that I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: That worked fine for me with your input string. Test PHP code separately, and provide me a demo on ideone if that doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: May I know why you decided to unmark this answer after long time today?

Comment: is it possible to redirect a url from this http://website.com/Song-Name.---mp3-download.html  to http://website.com/song-name-mp3-download.html in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try our tested generic [.htaccess file](https://github.com/samsonos/htmlapp/blob/master/www/.htaccess):

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

# Remove www from domain 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Without slash redirect to slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Redirect index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

# Redirect all requests to init script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You will find other useful SEO Apache tweaks, such as index.php to / redirect, case sensisitive redirection is not correct for SEO, you should find and change place in your code which creates different case urls.

Answer (score -1):

try `strolower($str);`
`Strtolower` should convert all your big letters, to small ones.
the opposite is `strtoupper`

Comment: how to redirect from uppercase to lowercase

Comment: add in your pattern (a-z)

Comment: i am new to php,, can you please explain more

Comment: RewriteRule ^mp3/([a-z]+)/?$ $1-mp3-download.html [L,NC,NE,R=301]
Something like this